# Useless use of private variable in void context in simple perl loop, no idea where the error is

Tags: perl

```
if ( $num_of_things > 1) {
    my $max_element = $num_of_things -1;
    for($max_element; $max_element >= 0; $max_element--) {
        $value_array[$max_element] = $starting_hash{$key}[$max_element];
    }
```

All of my variables not initialized in this code snippet have been initialized as part of the larger subroutine (which I don't want to put up due to length). I'm not sure where I'm getting the useless use of private variable in void context error in this code, my compiler is telling me it's the last line (with nothing but the closing brace "}"). All help is hugely appreciated as I've been staring at this loop for almost an hour with no idea what is wrong.

Comment: **Moderator note**: Keep comments to requesting clarification necessary to answer the question - they needn't be used for other purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move initialization (and declaration) of $max_element into `for` statement.
[see [ooga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3213868/ooga) comment ]

```
for( my $max_element=$num_of_things-1; $max_element>= 0; $max_element--) {
    $value_array[$max_element] = $starting_hash{$key}[$max_element];
}
```

Comment: Or without the C-style loop: `foreach my $max_element (reverse 0 .. $num_of_things - 1) { }`

Comment: Or, if `@value_array` is empty coming into this, since there's no dependency in the loop body on the ordering, just create it with a map: `my @value_array = map { $starting_hash{$key}[$_] } 0 .. $num_of_things-1;`

Comment: Thanks. I'll delete the question, but will it remove any reputation points or whatever you get from answering this? I don't wanna take those away if you took the time to answer this lol (assuming u care about them)

Comment: @chrisyyy There's no need to delete the question, it's perfectly on-topic, well-scoped, and answerable. In fact, you *can't* delete it because this answer was upvoted.